# Is it possible to get the normal login screen when resuming from suspend?

Tags: suspend, lightdm, login-screen, lock-screen

I noticed that the login screen that I get when the system first boots up is different from the login screen I see after I resume from suspend. I'm wondering if it is possible to get the same login screen that I saw when it first booted up as the one I get when I resume the system from suspend. I think the first boot login one is called LightDM greeter or something, not sure about the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

first remove `gnome-screensaver`

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Then install Lightlocker

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:light-locker/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install light-locker
```

For more info on the project see [Lightlocker's github page](https://github.com/the-cavalry/light-locker)

Answer (score 0):

LightDM launches `unity-greeter`, which shows the login screen. You can click *Switch User* on the unlock screen in order to return to the `unity-greeter` screen.

Comment: That sort of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? OP wants this automatically, not just clicking a button to have the normal screen.

Comment: @minerz029 I disagree. The OP did not mention he knows about this and I think it's a viable answer. I would argue that a single click is a better option than adding a PPA and removing a package that is part of `ubuntu-desktop`. Moreover, the PPA page says it takes you back to the LightDM greeter, but a standard Unity desktop is using `unity-greeter`. Plus, it says you may have to add custom keyboard shortcuts to make it work. It's not really shown in the answer that it provides exactly what the OP wants. With respect, I'll say again that a single click may be just the thing he's looking for.